# Feature paging with ArcGIS map service vs feature service

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service, feature-service

I'm about to implement an integration that involves reading all features from a layer on a municipal ArcGIS server.  There are at least two ways to go about this, including use of a Feature Service and a Map Service.  Are the solutions essentially equivalent?  In other words, can I use the Map Service to query and page through results in the same way, or in a way that is equally efficient and problem free, as I can using the Feature Service?  Both solutions appear to involve pulling IDs down and using offsets, there aren't for example 'next' and 'previous' links to utilize, from what I can see.  I am reading documentation on the Map Service presently and see ways forward, but want to see if anyone who has done this can answer this question and possibly provide other guidance as to whether I want to instead go with the Feature Service.

Answer (score 1):

After implementing the solution: the MapService worked just fine; I was told since that the only reason to use the FeatureService instead is if I needed the ability to update data as well.